# How to find position in two arrays in Java without java.util.Arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I have two arrays: names[10] and points[10]

names contains the players names, points their points

I want to write a method with parameters String newName and int newPoints that

1. finds the correct position according to the points (so newPoints=500 gets placed between array value
   300 and 600)
2. moves all values of points and names 1 position backwards in the index - to create a space for the
   newPoints and newName
3. saves the value of newPoints and newName in the empty array-spaces

I can't figure how to find the correct position in the array points[]

Here is my approach up to this point:

```
public void enterSorted(String nameNew, int pointsNew) {
    int indexPlace;
    for(int i = points.length-1; i >= 0; i--) { //starts with i=10 (last array entry); stops when i is below 0 
        
      if(points[i] > pointsNew) {
        indexPlace = i+1;
        System.out.println("indexPlace "+indexPlace+" was saved. ");
        break;
      }
      System.out.println("points[" + i + "] ("+points[i]+ "is smaller than pointsNew - proceeding");
    }
  }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you share your effort?

Comment: Some sort of tree might be more apt for this use case? Maybe Binary search tree

Comment: @maloomeister I tried to compare the values to each and every other value in the points array with a for loop containing an if-statement. I just thought there must be a simpler solution

Comment: @JudgeVFX share the code that you tried and point to where you got stuck.

Comment: @maloomeister I wrote the code and project in German, give me a minute to translate the variables etc.

Comment: @maloomeister just edited and posted it :)

Comment: for an array with 10 fields the index goes from 0 to 9 you must start with for(int i = (points.length - 1); i >= 0; i--) this is why you are out of Bounds points[10] does not exist!

Comment: Try `for(int i = points.length; --i >= 0;)` (`points.length` is indeed out of bounds)

Comment: why not use a map?

Comment: @MauricePerry Yep, thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, since you always look for the right position in the array, we can assume, that our two array are sorted with increasing points, so we don't need to do any sorting on our side, only inserting.
For that we search the first position for which the amount of points is higher that what we have (I initialized all with the max int, otherwise there are zeros in the unused fields). Then we can move backwards the ones from that position to the last defined one (I decided to define an index for the first undefined field, but you can only check for maxInt, though with this variable we can check if the array is full) and finally write our data.
If pos == firstUndef, we are behind all already defined and do not need to move anything.

```
public class Tested {
    
    public String[] names = new String[10];
    public int[] points = new int[10];
    public int firstUndef = 0;

    public void initPoints() {
        for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
            points[i] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }
    }
    
    public void addPlayer(String name, int point) {
        assert(firstUndef < points.length); // if false there is no room left in the arrays
        for (int i = 0; i <= firstUndef; i++) { // We only need to check for those defined and one more
            if (points[i] > point) {
                insertAt(name, point, i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void insertAt(String name, int point, int pos) {
        if (pos < firstUndef) {
            for (int i = (firstUndef - 1); i >= pos; i--) {
                points[i + 1] = points[i];
                names[i + 1] = names[i];
            }
        }
        points[pos] = point;
        names[pos] = name;
        firstUndef++;
    }

}
```

And you can use and test it like that:

```
Tested t = new Tested();
t.initPoints();

t.addPlayer("Peter", 300);
t.addPlayer("Frank", 600);
t.addPlayer("Avid", 500);

assert(t.names[0].equals("Peter"));
assert(t.names[1].equals("Avid"));
assert(t.names[2].equals("Frank"));
```

BTW: do not set the variables public, I only did this to test it fast.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the effort! Ill definitely try implementing this approach

Comment: The important thing is that you use initPoints at the beginning or nothing will be inserted at all, otherwise it should work fine. I also changed one line after looking at the other answer, who only goes check for the defined positions.

Answer (score 0):

Please DELETE <sub>[nobody](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13510609) cannot delete it</sub>

Question was changed after answer posted - `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` should be a common question in SO

---

For future, more OO: instead of arrays, use a `List` or even `SortedMap` with a record like:
`public record Player(String name, int points) { }`